# Perfect/Swift Compilation Working in OSX, Failing in Linux

Tags: linux, swift, swift3, perfect

So I'm using Perfect server to develop an application that returns values to a client. At the moment, it requires it to download some data from another API, process it, and send it down to a client.

For some reason however, it compiles fine in OSX but not in Linux. Linux doesn't seem to like the types, but I don't see how there's a difference. I've installed Swift 3.0.1 on Linux, and since I have Xcode 8.1 on OSX, it is the same version as well (yes, I checked).

Here is where the compiler is failing in Linux:

```
swift: /home/buildnode/disk2/workspace/oss-swift-3.0-package-linux-ubuntu-14_04/swift/lib/Sema/CSApply.cpp:3223: swift::Expr *(anonymous namespace)::ExprRewriter::visitCoerceExpr(swift::CoerceExpr *): Assertion `!failed && "Not convertible?"' failed.
...
1.  While type-checking 'getAllPrices' at /root/app/Sources/ValueProcessing.swift:104:9
2.  While type-checking expression at [/root/app/Sources/ValueProcessing.swift:116:17 - line:116:58] RangeText="errors["bw"] = bw.1 as AnyObject?"
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Aborted
```

Here are the lines in question by the compiler:

104:

```
class func getAllPrices(_ code: String, isAlive: Bool, countryCode: String) -> ([BuyPriceObject]?, [String:AnyObject]?){
```

116:

```
errors["bw"] = bw.1 as AnyObject?
```

In this snippet, the 'getAllPrices' fucntion returns a tuple which I have named 'bw'. I append all errors returned to an "error" dictionary where they are stored optionally as AnyObject. The reason I make the dictionary optional is in case the function returns no errors of course.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. Silly of me to make this mistake but here it is:

As you can see I tried storing and then returning an **optional AnyObject** value:

```
errors["bw"] = bw.1 as AnyObject?
```

However the 'getAllPrices' function defines a return value of a **non-optional AnyObject** type for the [String:AnyObject] dictionary:

```
class func getAllPrices(_ code: String, isAlive: Bool, countryCode: String) -> ([BuyPriceObject]?, [String:AnyObject]?){
```

Swift on OSX doesn't seem to care (both in terminal and in Xcode it built, don't ask me why), but Linux swift seems to be a bit stricter.

Solution:

```
errors["bw"] = bw.1 as AnyObject
```